# Agregar campos con javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

Estoy haciendo un formulario dinamico, hasta el momento ya me agrega los campos que requiero, sin embargo, tengo un problema al calcular el subtotal de cada fila como se muestra en la siguiente imagen, solo obtengo el calculo para la primer fila, y si agrego una mas ya no se calcula el subtotal como en la primer fila, alguien reconoce mi error, he intentado con otros metodos de agregacion de filas pero consigo el mismo resultado, espero contar con su ayuda
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo de mi formulario

```
<form id="demo-form2" action="" method="POST" data-parsley-validate class="form" autocomplete="off">
            @csrf
            <!-- Start second data -->
            <h4>Conceptos</h4>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" name="descripcion[]" id="descripcion" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="Descripción" value=""/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" id="unidad" name="unidad[]" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="Unidad">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" id="cantidad" name="cantidad[]" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" title="cantidad" placeholder="Cantidad"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" name="pu[]" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" title="pu" placeholder="P. U."/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">
                    <h5 title="subtotal">0</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-sm btn-info add_button form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Agregar</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Con esta parte de codigo agrego las filas y calculo el subtotal

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
    var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
    var wrapper = $('.form'); //Input field wrapper
    var fieldHTML = '<div class="form-group">' +
                        '<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">' +
                            '<input type="text" name="descripcion[]" id="descripcion" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="Descripción"/>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">' +
                            '<input type="text" id="unidad" name="unidad[]" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="Unidad">' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">' +
                            '<input type="text" id="cantidad" name="cantidad[]" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" title="cantidad" placeholder="Cantidad"/>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">' +
                            '<input type="text" name="pu[]" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" title="pu" placeholder="P. U."/>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">' +
                            '<h5 title="subtotal">0</h5>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger remove_button" title="Remove field"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>' +
                    '</div>';

    var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
    $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
        if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
            x++; //Increment field counter
            $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
        x--; //Decrement field counter
    });

    $(".form-group").keyup(function(){
        var cantidad=$(this).find("input[title=cantidad]").val();
        var pu=$(this).find("input[title=pu]").val();

        $(this).find("[title=subtotal]").html(parseInt(cantidad)*parseInt(pu));

        //subtotal = cantidad * pu;
        //document.formulario_01.subtotal.value = subtotal;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que cada vez que haces click sobre el botón agregar lo único que haces es agregar los elemenos al DOM dinámicamente y el evento de keyup sólo se captura en el primer .form-group (pues sólo existía ese cuando se hizo la carga de la aplicación).

Para solucionarlo, debes asociar el evento con un on(), así

```
$(document).on('keyup', ".form-group", function () {
    var cantidad = $(this).find("input[title=cantidad]").val();
    var pu = $(this).find("input[title=pu]").val();

    $(this).find("[title=subtotal]").html(parseInt(cantidad) * parseInt(pu));

    //subtotal = cantidad * pu;
    //document.formulario_01.subtotal.value = subtotal;
});
```

Agrego fragmento de código con la modificación del evento keyup, para que lo puedas probar haciendo click en el botón e Ejecutar. Te invito a que en próximas preguntas agregues fragmentos de códigos de la misma forma.

Más información acerca de método on() de jQuery puedes ir a la documentación aquí https://api.jquery.com/on/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
    var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
    var wrapper = $('.form'); //Input field wrapper
    var fieldHTML = '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">' +
        '<input type="text" name="descripcion[]" id="descripcion" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="Descripción"/>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">' +
        '<input type="text" id="unidad" name="unidad[]" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="Unidad">' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">' +
        '<input type="text" id="cantidad" name="cantidad[]" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" title="cantidad" placeholder="Cantidad"/>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">' +
        '<input type="text" name="pu[]" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" title="pu" placeholder="P. U."/>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">' +
        '<h5 title="subtotal">0</h5>' +
        '</div>' +
        '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger remove_button" title="Remove field"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>' +
        '</div>';

    var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
    $(addButton).click(function () { //Once add button is clicked
        if (x < maxField) { //Check maximum number of input fields
            x++; //Increment field counter
            $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function (e) { //Once remove button is clicked
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
        x--; //Decrement field counter
    });

    $(document).on('keyup', ".form-group", function () {
        var cantidad = $(this).find("input[title=cantidad]").val();
        var pu = $(this).find("input[title=pu]").val();

        $(this).find("[title=subtotal]").html(parseInt(cantidad) * parseInt(pu));

        //subtotal = cantidad * pu;
        //document.formulario_01.subtotal.value = subtotal;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="demo-form2" action="" method="POST" data-parsley-validate class="form" autocomplete="off">
            @csrf
            <!-- Start second data -->
            <h4>Conceptos</h4>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" name="descripcion[]" id="descripcion" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="Descripción" value=""/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" id="unidad" name="unidad[]" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="Unidad">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" id="cantidad" name="cantidad[]" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" title="cantidad" placeholder="Cantidad"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" name="pu[]" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" title="pu" placeholder="P. U."/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">
                    <h5 title="subtotal">0</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-sm btn-info add_button form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Agregar</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```